# Previously defined customWorkspace is missing during post stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In my Jenkins pipeline, I aim to run all stages on a single node due to the interdependency between the stages. To accomplish this, I've specified a global agent at the top level with a custom workspace defined. Unfortunately, when executing the pipeline, Jenkins encounters an error regarding the missing workspace during the post stage. If this isn't a bug, what is the best way to ensure that the custom workspace is available in the post stage? While I'm aware of the 'ws' directive to set the workspace manually, I am exploring alternative solutions.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label "my_node"
            customWorkspace "..."
        }
    }
    environment {...}
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            ...
        }
        stage('Docker') {
            ...
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            script {
                sh '''#!/bin/bash
                    echo "Clean up"
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```